# cmake command CXX compiler ABI info failed

Tags: ios, gcc, compiler-construction, cmake

I am trying to install opengl and run the cmake file, it gives these errors. Please help regarding what are the reasons and how to correct this​

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 5.0.0
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 5.0.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
```

Comment: You may want to tag [opengl] to get more visibility.

Comment: What is your cmake version?

Answer (score 6):

What is your operating system? Asking this because I had a similar problem recently: under Windows 10 I tried to compile several C++ projects using Cygwin and CMake in it and the detection of C and C++ compiler ABI information failed all the time.

Managed to solve the problem in the following way: in Cygwin's root directory, you can find CMake's installed files probably under the path `usr/share/cmake-3.6.2`. (Note that CMake's version number may differ in your system since you asked your question years before.) This path should be accurate (or at least default) under Linux, as well.

Inside the `Modules` directory you can find the `CMakeDetermineCompilerABI.cmake` file which describes how CMake determines the compilers' ABI info. When I added several extra logging statements to this file I realized that CMake, besides not generating all the necessary files, used some binaries from Strawberry Perl (`C:\Strawberry\bin\...`) I installed on my system not so long ago and for completely different reasons.

Finding this odd I removed Strawberry (I didn't need it anymore) and CMake started to work properly. :) (It didn't seem okay to use something external in Cygwin anyway.) Another workaround could be to remove Strawberry from the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: You are my hero and just saved my day! Indeed Strawberry disrupted a lot on my cygwin install. And once removed (Don't need it any more either), everything works like a charm! Thank you very much!